# Azure server respose time issue (Nodejs app)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-web-app-service

I have developed an app in Nodejs bu using Azure mobile services and AngularJS but often server response time is very high. As it keep on fluctuating from 900 - 15000 ms and also it got stuck most of the time and stop responding.
I have azure website in Standard Mode with auto scale from 1-3 and Small 1 core with 1.75 GB memory service. Also I am using nodejs npm as:
express, http, path, azure, fs, formidable, url, unzip, request

I have also checked error logs but it does not print any logs for error or issues. Is there any way to debug the issue from server level and code level. What is azure normal response time for Nodejs basic app.
Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: You mention using Mobile Services, but then mention using Azure Websites. Can you please edit your question to clarify where the server response time issue is?

Comment: We have a similar setup and have experienced outages and downtime intermittently since 10:00 GMT.

Comment: I wonder if using "Always On" in the configuration tab might help? I don't actually know if that impacts Node.js apps or not.